# Can't show .mov file on html5 video tag on iPhone

Tags: iphone, html, video, mov

I tried different ways to show a .mov video ("ISO Media, Apple QuickTime movie" on linux) in HTML5 page with Iphone, but it isn't working.

My code is:

```
<video width="320" height="240">
 <source src="test.mov">
</video>
```

With all desktop browser (chrome, firefox....) I can show the video.

Any Idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the right codec? H.264?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using `<source>` tag use `<src>` attribute of `<video>` as below and you will see the action.

```
<video width="320" height="240" src="test.mov"></video>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per HTML5 standards the only videos that are trully supported cross browser are MP4, ogg, and WebM. All other video files are not guaranteed to work with the standard html5 video player.

You can read more about it at this website.
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

Alternatevily you can look for other video players that can help you make this for you.

Hope this helps.

Comment: We can't trust our government, parents and now w3schools... who can I trust now a days

Comment: trust the authority: MDN, W3C

Answer (score 0):

The .MOV media type (Quicktime movies) is not supported in HTML5 browsers using the `video` element at this time. I recommend you encode those to MP4 (MPEG4).

But you can try this HTML below. The new `video` HTML5 element will not work as it supports limited media types (MP4, OGG, or WEBM). Using the older HTML `embed` or `object` elements forces the browser to use a plugin to support the video, if one exists. If your Quicktime movie plays, it will depend on how Apple and their Safari browser manage the plugin or player for this media type:

```
<embed id="embed1" src="test.mov" type="video/quicktime" style="width:320px;height:240px;">
  <noembed>Your browser does not support this media object or the embed element.</noembed>
</embed>
```